# Use winforms control with transparent background in MFC

Tags: c#, winforms, mfc, transparent-control

all.
I'm writting a MFC App that use Winforms user controls in it.

I made a rounded control with c# and placed it on my MFC dialog using MFC-hosting technology.
But the control does not show its background transparently.
So, it looks very poor. I tried to set control properties related transparency but it's useless.

Who can help me to make my control pretty?

Best regards.

Comment: Built-in support for transparency in the Control class only works if the parent is a Control derived class as well.  You'll need to look at overriding CreateParams to turn on WS_EX_TRANSPARENT.  Not as easy to get right.